# Why does ESLint trigger lint errors on while(true) using fibers?

Tags: javascript, eslint, node-fibers

I have come JS code with some infinite loops (we're using node-fibers to allow things to happen).

ESLint hates:

```
while (true) {

}
```

because of the constant condition.

The following is allowed though:

```
for(;;) {

}
```

Beyond just feeding the lintbeast, are there any objective reasons to favour `for` over `while` (or vice versa)?

**NOTE**: This question is explicitly requesting objective reasons and so is not simply opinion based.

Comment: Since performance is not usually a concern in infinite loops... who cares?

Comment: Is this with vanilla eslint or with plugins? (never used it myself)

Comment: Not sure why so many are downvoting, this seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: @ssube well performance isn't the only consideration in a well formed program... so I (and potentially others) care. Hence the question.

Comment: @glcheetham vanilla eslint. There's a rule (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-constant-condition) that trips on this. I could disable the rule, but then I'd miss more subtle and inappropriate constant conditions.

Comment: My guess would be, `for (;;)` is more obvious that it was intentional than is `while (true)`. Personally I'd do whatever is more readable.

Comment: This looks like an opinion based question. The while loop is the convention most people use, because it reads in a spoken word fashion. Ie "while true" is universally known to indicate an infinite loop, "for semicolon semicolon" does not immediately indicate that.

Comment: @BryceDrew the question is not "is it a good practice", it's "why does this particular library hold that opinion" which is in fact _not_ opinion based. If you read my answer - there is also nothing opinion based about it.

Comment: @Dancrumb that was largely sarcasm. This still fits the definition of an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These rules about infinite loops are from before generators were a thing and are not even aware of fibers.

Under the assumption that every function never suspends and returns (like a generator, `async`-keyword function or a fiber) the rule makes a lot of sense to warn against constants in loops.

Now that times have changed - the rule no longer makes sense and what you're doing is perfectly fine.

If we check the [eslint repo](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2375) it was discussed and deemed "not important enough to acknowledge" in the meantime:

> I don't think this makes sense as a built-in exception. If you're doing that, then it's best to manually disable the rule in the generator using a comment.

The workaround `for(;;)` was suggested but everyone involved understands it's a hack for this particular case.

Disable the rule.

Comment: inb4: Yes, I'm aware that generators "are a thing" in Mozilla Firefox for around 6 years now - I meant as in "standard in Node".